# Cast Mágico - Converter String para variados tipos de Objetos

Tags: java

Classe:

```
@Entity
public class ReportParam extends AbstractModel implements JRParameter {

@Column
private String nome;

@Column
private String descricao;

@Column
private Class<?> classe;
```

O objetivo:

Usar o atributo instanciado reportParam.getClasse() como cast em um linha de codigo, na situação especifica, recebo uma String "10/01/2018", e preciso converter ela para Date e/ou demais tipos (Integer, String,...) da seguinte maneira:

```
//Cast Magico?
minhaData = (reportParam.getClasse()) "10/01/2018";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando reflection, você pode tentar instanciar um `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`, passando `String.class` como parametro para ele. PORÉM, o objeto que você quer instanciar deve ter um construtor que receba String, senão ocorrerá uma exceção.

```
Constructor c = reportParam.getClasse().getConstructor( String.class );
minhaData = c.newInstance( "10/01/2018" );
```